# How do I make a "Match" Function analyze from right to left?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am analyzing how many months since last purchase from client. Clients are in the row and columns are the months. I have the exact formula I need; the only thing is that it doesn't analyze from right to left. So instead of counting blank cells since last purchase it is counting blank cells up to first purchase.

[image]

Current formula: `=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(C7:L7),0)-1`

I tried to play around with adding in index as well as offset formulas but it seems as if these formulas are used more for cross analyzing columns and rows. Please Help!

Comment: Why not test for a blank from the current month -1 then current month -2 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
=TAKE(SCAN(0,A2:H2,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",0,a+1))),,-1)
```

Or actually this:

```
=REDUCE(0,A2:H2,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",0,a+1)))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`=COLUMN(H:H)-MAX(IF(A2:H2,COLUMN(A:H),0))`

Or spillable:

```
=LET(a,A2:H3,
     MAX(COLUMN(a))- 
     BYROW(a,LAMBDA(b,MAX(IF(b,COLUMN(a),0)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
=COLUMNS(A2:H2)-XMATCH(TRUE,A2:H2<>"",0,-1)
```

or

```
=COLUMN(H2)-LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:H2<>""),COLUMN(A2:H2))
```